# Red glitches in video after installing a GeForce

Tags: ubuntu, video, nvidia-geforce, compiz, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an Intel DG45ID as my motherboard, with a Core2Duo e4700.

I was using the onboard video (X4500HD) until I could buy a decent video card. So, last week I installed a Geforce 9800GT.

But after installing the proper drivers in my Compiz-enabled Ubuntu 9.04 via Jockey, I'm getting red glitches VERY frequently on every video I play, at any player and any format.

If I do "*ALT+F2* > metacity --replace", switching out from Compiz, the glitching stops.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: I should say too that the red glitches happen __only inside__ the video area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really sounds like a hardware problem to me.  Any chance you can pop the card in another computer to verify?  Alternately, you could bump down to an earlier driver version.

Comment: I can't test the GeForce in another computer =( I'll try older driver and see if it stops. =]

Comment: finally. I couldn't find an easy way to install old drivers (jockey only shows the latest one, I think). So I went to Nvidia site and, tada, the REALLY latest driver fixes my problem. I was using v180, and I'm using now v185. Thank you =D

Answer (score 0):

Could also be a heat issue. Make sure you have proper ventilation inside your computer case.

Comment: Yes I have. Its big and have enough space for the air to flow easily. The video card also has a cooler. I don't think the problem is heat.. =S